# Looping in batch script based on the number of input arguments

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I would like to accept a variable number of inputs (filenames) from user and loop over a statement based on the number of inputs provided by the user. I wrote the following to achieve the same:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set argC = 0
for %%x in (%*) do Set /A argC+=1

ECHO Start of Loop
ECHO %argC%
ECHO !argC!

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,!argC!) DO (
  <move command here over the user provided arguments %1, %2 etc, we don't know how many filenames>
)
```

Now, I would like to replace `ECHO %%i` with a command and pass the file names entered by the user one by one in the same order. For example, if the user provides "a.txt" and "b.txt" as inputs if I replace `ECHO %%i` with a move command, how can I do that?

It would be great if someone could suggest an alternative or point out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: you need `%%i` instead of `%i` in the second loop.

Comment: @npocmaka Thanks, I thought the problem was with the loop condition. I have modified the question to add some other problem I face now. Could you look into it?

Comment: after the edit, the question is unclear. _"For example, if the user provides "a.txt" and "b.txt" as inputs if I replace ECHO %%i with a move command"_ What do you mean? replace a with b? copy them elsewhere? Please edit your question and clarify what you want, not give fake examples, just expected output samples and proper input.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I have edited the question. See if the edit helps to understand. I meant I wanted to replace the entire `ECHO` statement with a move command so that the loop executes move in loop for all the files that has been provided by the user. In my example it would run twice once move "a.txt" and then move "b.txt".

Comment: so then what does the count have to do with it?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard My knowledge is limited here, I just wanted to know if there is a dynamic way of processing user inputs. Or an implicit function that would help achieve what I'm trying.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%i in (%*) do echo "%%~i"
```

should echo your supplied parameters nicely. Replace the `echo` with commands to suit.

BTW - Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move files based on user input. Simply do:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (%*) do (
 echo move %%a
)
```

So from cmdline you would do `mybatchfile.cmd file1.txt file2.txt` etc.

OR

```
@echo off
set /p "files=Enter Files to copy : "
for %%a in (%files%) do (
 echo move %%a
)
```

This would simply prompt the user for files when running the file.